# i'm using firebase 4 , swift 3 and ios 10 and i can't find FIRAuth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, ios-3.x

i'm using firebase 4 , swift 3 and ios 10 and i can't find FIRAuth as i'm trying to work on a project to build a messenger app .
can anyone help me with it?

Comment: The [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start) contains a wealth of information including the new [API in Firebase 4](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide#detailed_list_of_changes)

Answer (score 6):

Firebase has removed the class prefixes in version 4, so it is now just `Auth`.